# How can I select what Gerber file a PCB layer should be added to?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication, gerber

I am trying to make a panelized PCB that can be sent to manufacturing. The panel consists of several different PCBs. I am having trouble with exporting the PCB layers to the correct Gerber file.

One of the PCB's power planes (Payload: Int2(PWR)) has been placed on an internal signal layer( .G1), when it sould be on the power plane layer (.GP2)

Is there an easy way to move it?

[image]

Comment: Which software? If the layer is a file named xxxx.G1, can it be renamed to xxxx.GP2?

Comment: Using Altium Designer. The problem is that the gerber file contains the info for multiple PCB at the same time. G1 contains the signal layer for other PCBs as well as the PWR plane for the payload PCB

Comment: All of the boards on a panel are physically produced on the same PCB so they must have the same stack up. Did you actually design two different stack ups of just name the layers differently? The manufacturer won't care about the layer names so long as they're physically the same position and thickness.